# Binary Recursive GCD algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, closed-form, gcd-and-lcm, recursive-algorithms

This is a pseudocode for a Binary GCD algorithm:

```
Input: a, b positive integers
Output: gcd(a, b)
    if a = 0 or b = 0 return a+b
    if a = 1 or b = 1 return 1
    if a is even
        if b is even return 2*gcd(a/2,b/2)
        else return gcd(a/2,b)
    else
        if b is even: return gcd(a, b/2)
        else
           if a < b return gcd((b-a)/2, a)
           else return gcd((a-b)/2, a)
```

What is the running time of this algorithm?

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? P.S. This is missing something: `else return(a/2,b)`.

Comment: I'm confused by what $n$ should be in $T(n)$ and what the cases should be.

Comment: You didn't even mention $n$ or $T(n)$ before. You should edit the question and clarify what it's about.

Comment: @dxiv apologies, I have now edited the question to clarify.

Comment: See the related [time complexity of below gcd algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472698/time-complexity-of-below-gcd-algorithm).